# For $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_{2021}$ the roots of $z^{2021}+z-1$, evaluate $\sum_i\frac{z_i^3}{z_i+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $\ldots$, $z_{2021}$ be the roots of the polynomial $z^{2021}+z-1$. Evaluate
> $$\frac{z_1^3}{z_1+1} +\frac{z_2^3}{z_2+1} +\frac{z_3^3}{z_3+1} +\cdots +\frac{z_{2021}^3}{z_{2021}+1} $$

I'm not really sure where to go from here, I saw how the polynomial factors:
$$(z^2 - z + 1)  (z^{n-2} + z^{n-3} - z^{n-5}  - z^{n-6} + z^{n-8} - \cdots + z^2 - 1)$$

Comment: What's the source of this question? The $2021$ suggests that it might be a contest.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** (If you're stuck, explain what you're tried.)

Find a polynomial whose roots are $ y_i = z_i + 1$. (You don't have to expand out the terms, just find a simple way to express it.)
Hence, calculate $ \sum \frac{1}{y_i} = \sum \frac{ 1}{ z_i + 1 }$. (Note that you don't have to calculate all of the terms of the previous polynomial.)

> This sum is 674.

Use $ \frac{ z_i^3  + 1 } { z_i + 1 } = z_i^2 - z_i + 1 $.

Hence, $\sum \frac{ z_i^3 } { z_i + 1 }  = \sum  z_i^2 - z_i + 1 - \frac{1}{z_i + 1 } $.

> Thus, the answer is $ 0   - 0 + 2021 - 674 = 1347$.

Comment: If $f(z) = z^(2021) + z - 1$ then the polynomial having roots $z_i + 1$ is $f(z-1)$, now to get $\sum \frac{1}{z_i + 1}$ that should be the coffienct of $z$ over the absolute term, I get that as 674, while the other answer here says 1347. Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: @dude076 I'm guessing that your mistake is you only read my solution halfway. You are right that $ \sum 1/(z_i + 1) = 674$. However, that doesn't contradict Marko's claim that the answer to the problem is 1347.

Comment: @dude076 (Fixed OP) While it turns out to be true that $ z^2 - z + 1 \mid z^{2021} + z - 1 $, why does that imply that $ \sum z_i^2 - z_i + 1 = 0 $? As an example, what is $ \sum x_i$ for the polynomial $ x^n - n x^{n-1}$?

Comment: I did not express my thoughts well, but it was wrong anyways. I cleared my misconception now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using residues and the function

$$f(z) = \frac{z^3}{z+1} \frac{q(1-z)/z+1}{z^q+z-1}
= \frac{z^2}{z+1} \frac{q+(1-q)z}{z^q+z-1}.$$

where $q\ge 4,$ an integer.

First we need to show that the poles from the term in $q$ are all simple.
We write for a pole $\rho$ the Taylor series of $g(z) = z^q+z-1$

$$g(z) = g(\rho) + g'(\rho) (z-\rho) + \cdots$$

We have $g(\rho) = 0$ and

$$g'(\rho) = q \rho^{q-1} + 1 = q \frac{1-\rho}{\rho} + 1
= \frac{q}{\rho} - q + 1$$

Supposing this were zero we would have

$$\rho = \frac{q}{q-1}.$$

Keeping in mind that $g(\rho) = 0$ this yields

$$\frac{q^q}{(q-1)^q} + \frac{q}{q-1} - 1 = 0
\quad\text{or}\quad
\frac{q^q}{(q-1)^{q-1}} = -1.$$

This is clearly impossible with $q\ge 4$ a positive integer
and hence $g'(\rho) \ne 0$ and the poles are simple.
Note also that $-1$ is not a root of $z^q+z-1$ by inspection.

Observe that with $\rho$ the finite poles other than minus one we have
(note that there is in fact no pole at zero)

$$\sum_\rho \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho} f(z)
= \sum_\rho \frac{\rho^3}{\rho+1}
(q(1-\rho)/\rho + 1)
\lim_{z\rightarrow \rho}
\frac{z-\rho}{z^q+z-1-(\rho^q+\rho-1)}
\\ = \sum_\rho \frac{\rho^3}{\rho+1}
(q(1-\rho)/\rho + 1) \frac{1}{q\rho^{q-1} + 1}
= \sum_\rho \frac{\rho^3}{\rho+1}.$$

Now residues sum to zero so our sum must be the residue at $-1$
with the sign flipped. The residue at infinity is zero by
inspection when $q\ge 4.$ We get

$$- \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1} f(z)
= - (-1)^3 \frac{1-2q}{(-1)^q-2}$$

for an end result of

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{2q-1}{2-(-1)^q}.}$$

In particular with $q$ being the current year $2021$ we find
the value

$$1347.$$