# roots of polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, $\cdots$, $z_{2021}$ be the roots of the polynomial $z^{2021}+z-1$. Evaluate$$\frac{z_1^3}{z_{1}+1}+\frac{z_2^3}{z_{2}+1}+\frac{z_3^3}{z_{3}+1}+\cdots+\frac{z_{2021}^3}{z_{2021}+1}.$$

In this problem, I saw that $$\frac{x^3}{x+1} = x^2-x+1 - \frac{1}{x+1}.$$ Then,
$$\sum z_i^2 = \left(\sum z_i\right)^2 - 2\sum z_iz_j = 0$$ and $\sum -z_i=1$from Vieta's formulas $\sum 1=2021$.

---

However, I am not able to find $\sum \frac{1}{z_i+1}$. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If $f(z)=z^{2021}+z−1$ then the polynomial having roots $z_i+1$ is $f(z−1)$, now to get $\sum \frac{1}{z_i+1}$  that should be the coefficient of $z$ over the absolute term, I get that as $674$.

Comment: @XIC22 I am not understanding what you are saying. Instead of saying it in brief, could you elaborate step-by-step [in an answer not a comment]

Comment: can someone explain?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma**: If $z$ is a root of $p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i$ where $z$ is non-zero, then $z^{-1}$ is a root of $q(z) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{n-i}z^i$.

Proof:

Suppose $z$ is a root of $p$, $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^i=0,$$ we divide by $z^n$, then we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^{i-n}=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(z^{-1})^{n-i}=0.$$

Let $n-i=j$, $$\sum_{j=0}^n a_{n-j}(z^{-1})^{j}=0$$

That is $z^{-1}$ is a root of $q$.

---

What the lemma says is given a polynomial with $z$ as a non-zero root, then $z^{-1}$ is a root for the polynomial obtained by reversing the coefficient order. Let's apply this result on our problem.

$$f(z)=z^{2021}+z-1$$

If $z$ is a root of $f$, then $z+1$ is a root of

$$g(z)= f(z-1)=(z-1)^{2021}+(z-1)-1=\sum_{i=0}^{2021}a_iz^i$$

where $a_0=-3, a_{1}=2021+1=2022$.

Hence, $$\sum \frac1{z_i+1}=-\frac{a_1}{a_0}=\frac{2022}{3}=674$$

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.